# SVN Commit results in E210002 (Network connection closed unexpectedly) - not using SSH

Tags: svn, pre-commit-hook

I'm trying to commit some changes to a SVN repository, but the commit results in an E210002 error. I am using plain SVN and not SVN+SSH as discussed in the other questions I found dealing with this error, thus the solutions for SVN+SSH don't work for me. The repository server is up and on a reliable connection, so it is not a network problem. What else could be causing this Error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, the Problem was a pre-commit-hook script (checking that files don't contain TAB characters), which crashes when it rejects multiple files. Fixing the committed files to pass the pre-commit checks fixed the error.

Strangely, the hook works well and produces the correct `E165001` error for a `TAB` in a single file and only fails when multiple files violate its rules; but this is another issue - as is the fact that a pre-commit script can crash the whole commit with a very confusing error message.